# Sailfish OS will not update

Tags: sailfish-os

I don't know if this is the right site for this question, but I need to know why Sailfish OS will not let me update. When I go into the updates in Settings and press Check for Update, it says there is no update found, but I'm on version 1.1.2.16, and 2.0 should be showing up. (I know, I'm on a really old version.) If anyone knows how to fix this, an answer would be helpful.

Comment: Yes. When I go into Settings > System Settings > Sailfish OS updates and click Check For Updates in the pulley menu, it says that it's checking for an update, then says I'm up to date, even though I'm using version 1.1.2.16. The latest release is 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better site for the question would be [together.jolla.com](https://together.jolla.com/questions/).

To diagnose this kind of situations more information would be needed. If you have developer mode enabled, from terminal app or with ssh connection to the device you can

- Check the output of `ssu status` (to make sure device model, release and domain are correct)
- Look for store related errors in `devel-su journalctl -fa` output during the update check

And another thing to note is that OTA system updates are not provided for the community ports of Sailfish OS on unofficial devices at the moment.

Comment: Okay, thanks so much, because I am actually using a community port of Sailfish OS. The Jolla Store won't work, either, do you think that may be related?